# Алгоритм обхода препятствий на плоскости

Tags: алгоритм, графы

[image: Граф]

Здравствуйте! Суть такова.

Есть несколько произвольных графов с прямоугольными элементами. Между элементами разных графов могут быть связи. Например такая, какая показана на рисунке красным цветом. Естественно, если просто соединять элементы напрямую, то связь будет пересекать другие элементы, чего мне не хотелось бы.
Я бы хотел показать эту связь примерно так, как указано на рисунке синим цветом.
Но у меня не получается придумать алгоритм, который бы отрисовывал линию, обходя препятствия.
Я очень прошу натолкнуть меня хоть на какую-то мысль. Пишу на Python для Inkscape, но язык неважен, важен сам алгоритм.

Сам я пришёл лишь к чему-то такому: пусть связь есть совокупность отрезков, заданных списком точек.

1. Сначала она состоит лишь из одного отрезка (двух точек).
2. Для каждого элемента графов проверяем, пересекает ли этот отрезок элемент.
3. Если пересекает, то ищем, с какой стороны - слева или справа.
4. Между двумя точками исходного отрезка вставляем две точки, задающих отрезок, параллельный стороне элемента и несколько отстоящий от него.
5. Теперь связь состоит из трёх отрезков.
6. Для каждого из полученных отрезков повторяем пункты 2-4, пока пункт 3 не перестаёт давать истину.

Пример работы алгоритма показан ниже  (последовательность по итерациям:зелёный - фиолетовый - оранжевый).
[image: Алгоритм]
Мне этот алгоритм кажется нерациональным как минимум по двум причинам:
1) На четвёртой итерации будет создан отрезок, который даёт крюк пути.
2) Если связей будет несколько, они могут накладываться друг на друга на некоторых участках, проходящих рядом с элементами.

Comment: По идее можно нарезать диаграмму на полосы по высоте (типа кирпичной кладки), построить граф с проходимыми-непроходимыми областями, и по нему запустить А*.

Comment: Хмм. Замостить плоскость тайлами со свойством проходимости? Я так понимаю, тайлы должны быть одинакового размера для корректной работы алгоритма?

Comment: Одинаковость совершенна не обязательно. А* работает на любом графе (любой размерности и связности). В данном случае будут лишь меняться "стоимости" перехода между "нодами (тайлами)"